# Email Sending Double

Tags: ee2, email

The website I am working on at the moment in ExpressionEngine2 requires candidates to apply for a job which is listed on the website. As soon as they apply for the job, the website consultant needs to be notified via email that a candidate has applied for job X.

I am using a module to set up and send the email (wording, attachments, settings etc) and the email only contains one line to send the email (`$send = $this->EE->email->Send();`), but sometimes sends out a double email - the exact same one.

How could this be?

Comment: Which module are you using?

Comment: Do you have this Chrome plugin installed? http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/2398/28

Comment: I am using my own custom module to send email

Comment: Could it be that the user is clicking the link twice before the script exits?